# Using ember-data RecordArray

Tags: ember.js, datatables, ember-data

I need inser data from model to dataTables "aaData:". I can't get objects from store at normal array, but as DS.RecordArray and what next? Console command to get some properties of some object is following command :

```
var dev = App.Model.Store.find("model")
dev.content.content[1]._data.someProperty
```

I don't know how to get this object or his property at javascript.
Please, help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Ember Data beta 1 or later you'd do this in a controller or route.

```
var dev = this.store.find("model");
// dev is a promise that will be resolved when/if
// the collection is actually loaded
dev.then(function(realDev){
    // at this point realDev is a DS.RecordArray
    // you could turn it into a real array by cally .toArray()
    var devAry = realDev.toArray();
    // then you can call get() on an item to retrieve a property
    var someProp = devAry[1].get('someProperty');
});
```

Comment: This works from console command line, but from ember view or controller don't. output is [] (empty array)

Comment: Can you post a JSBin illustrating your problem?  That code works for me.  http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1094/edit

Comment: Your code works for me too, I don't know what I did wrong. Anyway how can I use the thingAry (from your jsbin) somewhere at javascript code? I tried this solution, but output is empty http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1106/edit

Comment: The issue in your bin is that you're trying to return a value from `things.then` and use it immediately.  In that example `things` is a promise, and it may not resolve (calling your `then` function) until after you've already called `controller.set('specialThing',...)`.  You'd want to set `specialThing` inside the resolving function, and then use observers to deal with it further.  Look at the `doSpeicalStuff` method on the `IndexController` here : http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1109/edit

Comment: Ok, but I still don't get access to specialThing in controller. If I comment "specialThing: null" nothing will change. I edited jsbin for show name at alert message: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1150/edit and this is undefined. The problem can be in "this.specialThing.name", I tried "this.get('specialThing')" and the result is the same.

Comment: First, don't comment out `specialThing : null`, you need that to fire the observers.  Second you can access the `name` of `specialThing` with either `this.get('specialThing.name')` or `this.get('specialThing').get('name')`.  Inside of Ember you always want to use `get` and `set`, and you should never directly assign or access properties.  Here's another working bin : http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1155/edit